# Are the countable (rayless) trees with wqo labels wqo?

Tags: co.combinatorics, lo.logic, order-theory

It has been proved by Corominas that the countable trees with vertex-labels coming from a better-quasi-ordered set are better-quasi-ordered. My question is whether this holds if we replace bqo by wqo both times:

**Question:** Let Q be a countable well-quasi-ordered set. Is the class of rayless, countable, rooted trees with vertices labeled by elements of Q well-quasi-ordered with respect to order-preserving and label-preserving injection?

*Label-preserving* here means that $\ell(x) \leq \ell(f(x))$ for every vertex x, where $f$ denotes the injection, and $\ell: V(T) \to Q$ the labelling. A tree is *rayless* if it contains no 1-way infinite path.

Comment: 1) Please give the definition of wqo 2) I have had Corominas as one of my professors (University of Lyon, France) : sympathetic, interesting, although not a born didactician...